# Nested selection loading time in mysql

Tags: mysql, nested, selection, loading

I have one table packets 
packets contains 2 fields id and total 
they are both bigint length 20 and primary keys 
only id is auto increment 
in every record total = id 
i got 10000 records let's say id = 1 - 10000 and total = 1 - 10000

i got 2 almost identical queries 1 results in a very very long loading time and one completes almost instantly.

very very long loading time:

```
set @i = 0; 

SELECT *

FROM packets as p1

WHERE p1.total in ( SELECT p2.total

FROM packets  as p2 where ( ( @i := ( @i + 1 ) )
```

very short loading time:

```
set @i = 0;

SELECT *

FROM packets as p1

WHERE p1.id in ( SELECT p2.id

FROM packets  as p2 where ( ( @i := ( @i + 1 ) )
```

this happens while the values of id and total are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> they are both bigint length 20 and primary keys

You cannot have two primary keys in one table.

It seems that you don't have an index on `packets.total`

Create it and see if it helps:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_packets_total ON packets (total)
```

Comment: Removing primary key and adding an index did the deal for me, i already was doing a workaround for another query, 
the other query was made working by just simply creating an index.

thanks a lot for your answer, it really did the deal for me!